# How to maintain login authentication in vue3 + vuex + firebase?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

Currently, the login is working fine, but when I refresh, the user information changes to null and then the user information is retrieved again. How do I solve this?
Please note that I do not want to use loading.

I retrieve user information from userStore like this.

```js
const userStore = {
...
  actions: {
    initAuth({ commit }: any) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
          commit('setUser', user);

          resolve(user);
        });
      });
    },
  },
...
}
```

App.vue

```js
const route = useRoute();
const store = useStore();
const user = ref(null);

onMounted(async () => {
  watchEffect(() => {
    const newUser = store.getters['userStore/getUser'];
    user.value = newUser;

    console.log(user.value);
  });

  if (user.value === null) {
    const storedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') as any);

    if (storedUser) {
      user.value = storedUser;
    }
  }

  await store.dispatch('userStore/initAuth');
});
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: your app's state will not automatically persist between reloads because it requires using browser memory.  you must opt-in to this type of behavior. See something like https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist